# contexts for "to learn" vs. "for learning"

Tags: word-usage

Consider the following sentences

> We came here to learn English.
>
> We came here for learning English.

I suppose most of us here would agree that both of them are grammatically correct.

And I thought they mean the same thing until a native speaker told me there is slight difference depending on contexts.

However, he didn't explain the difference and contacts. Could someone help with me on this?

Comment: I have no idea what your informant meant by "contacts" in this context. The first is far more natural: I'm finding it hard to come up with a context in which anybody would say the second.

Comment: The OP probably meant to say "contexts", not "contacts".

Comment: It is more than a "slight" difference: the second is not idiomatic, and would immediately mark you as a non-native speaker. If you want to use the preposition **for** it could be "We came here for English classes" but the first is more natural.

Comment: @WeatherVane Your comment is so informative, thank you! And, the second is grammatically correct, right?

Comment: This is not a good resource **for learning English**. The second one is not grammatical in English.

Answer (score 0):

> We came here to learn English.

Correct.

> We came here for learning English.

Wrong.

"For" in this context should have a noun as it's object: "for a thing".

> We came here for the cupcakes.

> We came here for a specific purpose.

"For" could be used with "learn":

> We came here for the purpose of learning English.

Notice that "purpose" is clearly a noun. "for the purpose of learning" and "to learn" are basically synonymous here.

How about this sentence:

> We came here for swimming.

Something's strange about that.

> We came here to swim.

Ok.

The next question, is *why*. What explains the rule? This is a conundrum, because as a native speaker I know what sounds right or wrong, without always being able to say the rules. It may be due to the fact that there's a difference between a *noun* and a *thing*.  Even though "learning" is grammatically a noun, it's more of an action than an object.

Comment: We came here for swimming *is* acceptable, though, with ‘swimming’ as a gerund.

Answer (score -2):

- "We came here to learn English" - It's in the past. We're not learning now.
- "We came here for learning English" - We're still here learning.

I think that could be the difference.